# a function that compute indegree and outdegree for each vertice using adjacency list representation

Tags: c++

I have a directed graph using adjacency list representation. But I am in a trouble. I want to write a function that compute indegree and outdegree for each vertice. Can you suggest me a solution in C++  ??
Here is my source code:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <list>
    using namespace std;

    // A directed graph using adjacency list representation
    class Graph
    {
        int V;    // No. of vertices in graph
        list<int> *adj; // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists

        // A recursive function used by printAllPaths()
        void printAllPathsUtil(int , int , bool [], int [], int &);

    public:
        Graph(int V);   // Constructor
        void addEdge(int u, int v);
    };

    Graph::Graph(int V)
    {
        this->V = V;
        adj = new list<int>[V];
    }

    void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v)
    {
        adj[u].push_back(v); // Add v to u’s list.
    }
```

Comment: At SO we encourage posters to attempt the problem themselves then we can help with specific problems that you may have. We will not write the code for you as this does not help you to learn as you would by going through the thinking and problem solving yourself. Please attempt to write the code yourself, the post what you have in your question.

Comment: Please go through your previous questions and mark the answers that solved your problem as accepted. This shows others that the question has been solved, and is helpful to those that answer your questions. It will also encourage more people to help you in the future..

Answer (score 1):

Simply take a graph and calculate the indegree and outdegree yourself. You will understand what you need to do.
I will give hint so that you can solve on your own

**Hint-1**

Outdegree is simple what is going out of a node. Think of what an adjacency list entry contains? That is all the nodes that is going from it. Got it!!

**Hint-2**

When looking at an age `a-->b` you will also give attention to `b`. So there is something going into `b` that must contribute to indegree. Isn't it? Traverse all the edges and then you will know...

[ You may have to use an array for `indegree` calculation]